# How to start three tasks which will run in order in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to start three tasks : The first one will read some emails, after it is completed a service which generates some graphs based on those emails will start and finally the graphs will be sent as zip files on email.
These tasks must run in this precise order:

dataReader -> graphGenerator -> emailSender.

I implemented this service, but I don't figure out why it doesn't work.

```
@Component
public class WeeklyEmailService {
    @Autowired
    private EmailSender emailSender;
    @Autowired
    private GraphGenerator graphGenerator;
    @Autowired
    private DataReader dataReader;
    @Autowired
    private CompanyRepository companyRepository;
    @Autowired
    private EmailConfigurer emailConfigurer;
    @Value("${mail.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${mail.password}")
    private String password;

    public void sendWeeklyEmail() {
        emailConfigurer.setUsername(username);
        emailConfigurer.setPassword(password);
        if (emailConfigurer.configure() != null) {
            System.out.println("Connection successfully established with mail server!");
        }
        Task<Void> reader = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                dataReader.readWeeklyEmails();
                return null;
            }
        };

        Task<Void> generator = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                companyRepository.getCompanyNames().forEach(company -> {
                    graphGenerator.generateGraphs(new DateTime().minusWeeks(1), new DateTime(), company);
                });
                return null;
            }
        };

        Task<Void> emailTask = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                emailSender.sendMailWithAttachment();
                return null;
            }
        };
        reader.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
            Thread generatorThread = new Thread(generator);
            generatorThread.start();
        });
        generator.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
            Thread emailThread = new Thread(emailTask);
            emailThread.start();
        });
        emailTask.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
            if (clean()) {
                System.out.println("Graphs Reports and ZIP files deleted from your computer");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Files which you want to delete do not exists");
            }
        });
        Thread readerThread = new Thread(reader);
        readerThread.start();
    }

    private boolean clean() {
        boolean cleaned = false;
        try {
            cleaned = Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get("graphs"));
            cleaned = Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get("reports"));
            cleaned = Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get("zip"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cleaned;
    }
}
```

If there is a better way to do that please advise me, Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some code which results in the same behaviour:
Simplified, perfectly in order, but no error handling.

```
Thread sendWeeklyEmailThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run()
    {
        readWeeklyEmails();
        generateGraphs();
        sendMailWithAttachment();
        clean(); //cleanup....
    }
});
sendWeeklyEmailThread.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also read more about `CompletableFuture` because is more useful, and easier to maintenance. Then read about `ExecutorService` because IMHO good option is predefine number of threads.

Example:

```
final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

new CompletableFuture<String>().supplyAsync(() ->  dataReader.readWeeklyEmails(), executorService);
```

Example for method:

```
private String readWeeklyEmails(){
    return "";
}
```

if you write your code like that, You have easy way to control your task's and possible exceptions